# Index/Match while looping through rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code, which I was hoping to use to look up values from columns 21 through to the last row in another sheet and return them to this sheet based on a value in column A in this sheet and column B in the other sheet.

When I use the code below I get an worksheet error. Could you please tell me why?

```
Dim wsMvOld As Worksheet
Dim wsMvFile As Worksheet
Dim wsColumn As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim FrRngCount As Range

Set wsMvOld = wbMVRVFile.Worksheets(2)

wbMVRVFile.Worksheets.Add().Name = "MV " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "dd-mm-yy")

Set wsMvFile = wbMVRVFile.ActiveSheet

Set FrRngCount = wsMvFile.Range("A:A")
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(FrRngCount)

lastColumn = wsMvFile.Cells(1, wsMvFile.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For wsColumn = 21 To lastColumn
For i = 2 To y
    wsMvFile.Columns(wsColumn).Cells(i) =     Application.Index(wsMvOld.Range(wsColumn), Application.Match(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Range("B:B"), 0))
Next i

Next wsColumn

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Forgot `WorksheetFunction` before `index`? But really why is everyone using worksheet functions in VBA XD

Comment: Let me try it. The reason why I am using worksheet functions is because I don't know any better solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: So I still get "Method Range of object worksheet failed" after adding WorksheetFunction. How would a lookup find look like? Isn't that just another worksheet function?

Comment: You didn't explicitly say which worksheet the `Columns.Count` is to be in, which may cause issues...change the line to `wsMvFile.Cells(1, wsMvFile.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: I don't see where you set the sheet variable to sheets.

Comment: I mean the [find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Comment: Also, add `Option Explicit` to the very top, which will force you to declare all variables, which should help cut down on errors.

Comment: Just made the requested Bruce/Scott to the code. @Bruce, your suggestion still returns the same error.

Comment: Ah! I see where the issue is. Use this formula: `Application.Index(wsMvOld.Columns(i).EntireColumn, Application.Match(wsMvNew.Range("A" & i), wsMvOld.Columns(2).EntireColumn, 0))`

Comment: Yes, that fixed the other error, but now the error has changed to "Object required".

Comment: @FindWindow - usually the find method is significantly slower than using MATCH or a variant array method - https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: @CharlesWilliams makes sense array would be fastest but it's only significant when searching lots of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This untested, but it replaces the worksheet function to vba find method.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim wsMvOld As Worksheet
Dim wsMvFile As Worksheet
Dim wsColumn As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim FrRngCount As Range

Set wsMvOld = wbMVRVFile.Worksheets(2)

Set wsMvFile = wbMVRVFile.Worksheets.Add()
wsMvFile.Name = "MV " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "dd-mm-yy")



Set FrRngCount = wsMvFile.Range("A:A")
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(FrRngCount)

lastColumn = wsMvFile.Cells(1, wsMvFile.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = 2 To y
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sMvOld.Range("B:B").Find(wsMvFile.Range("A" & i))
    For wsColumn = 21 To lastColumn
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            wsMvFile.Columns(wsColumn).Cells(i).Value = wsMvOld.Cells(rng.Row, wsColumn)
        Else
            wsMvFile.Columns(wsColumn).Cells(i).Value = 0
        End If
    Next wsColumn
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: So the good news is, that the error is gone now. But the macro takes a lot of time now and it does not seem to populate the columns. Any idea why?

Comment: Try the edit I flipped the loops, now it only loops on the column if the row is true.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks so much Scott. If I would like to show a zero if the value cannot be found in the other sheet, is there an easy way to amend the loop?

Comment: Using FIND is usually significantly slower than using Worksheetfunction.Match or a variant array: see https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: @CharlesWilliams fascinating I would have assumed that the opposite would be true.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks Scott, your help is much appreciated!